# vim plugin (python) - can't find liburl2 module

Tags: python, vim, plugins

I am developing a vim plugin in python language using the steps mentioned here : http://brainacle.com/how-to-write-vim-plugins-with-python.html

I checked that :echo has('python') returns 1 and basic python commands work, but when I try to  import "urllib2" module as mentioned in above link, it throws the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named urllib2
```

On the other hand, if I create a simple python program and try to import urllib2 in it, the program works fine.
So the problem is only within vim plugin.

Details of my vim installation:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.2 (2008 Aug 9, compiled Aug  9 2008 12:52:42)
MS-Windows 64-bit console version
Compiled by George@GEORGE-VPC1
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+arabic +autocmd -balloon_eval -browse ++builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent 
+clientserver +clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments 
+cryptv +cscope +cursorshape +dialog_con +diff +digraphs -dnd -ebcdic 
+emacs_tags +eval +ex_extra +extra_search +farsi +file_in_path +find_in_path 
+float +folding -footer +gettext/dyn -hangul_input +iconv/dyn +insert_expand 
+jumplist +keymap +langmap +libcall +linebreak +lispindent +listcmds +localmap 
+menu +mksession +modify_fname +mouse -mouseshape +multi_byte_ime/dyn 
+multi_lang -mzscheme -netbeans_intg -osfiletype +path_extra -perl +postscript 
+printer +profile +python/dyn +quickfix +reltime +rightleft -ruby +scrollbind 
+signs +smartindent -sniff +statusline -sun_workshop +syntax +tag_binary 
+tag_old_static -tag_any_white -tcl -tgetent -termresponse +textobjects +title 
-toolbar +user_commands +vertsplit +virtualedit +visual +visualextra +viminfo 
+vreplace +wildignore +wildmenu +windows +writebackup -xfontset -xim 
-xterm_save -xpm_w32 
   system vimrc file: "$VIM\vimrc"
   user vimrc file: "$HOME\_vimrc"
  2nd user vimrc file: "$VIM\_vimrc"
   user exrc file: "$HOME\_exrc"
  2nd user exrc file: "$VIM\_exrc"
Compilation: cl -c /W3 /nologo  -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_PATHDEF -DWIN32   -DFEAT_CSCOPE             -DWINVER=0x0400 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0400  /Fo.\ObjCY/ /Ox /GL -DNDEBUG  /Zl /MT -DFEAT_MBYTE_IME -DDYNAMIC_IME -DFEAT_MBYTE -DDYNAMIC_ICONV -DDYNAMIC_GETTEXT -DFEAT_PYTHON -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON  -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON_DLL=\"python25.dll\" -DMSWINPS -DFEAT_HUGE /Fd.\ObjCY/ /Zi
 Linking: link /RELEASE /nologo /subsystem:console /LTCG:STATUS oldnames.lib  kernel32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib gdi32.lib  comdlg32.lib ole32.lib uuid.lib /machine:AMD64 /nodefaultlib  libcmt.lib   user32.lib     /nodefaultlib:python25.lib      /PDB:vim.pdb -debug
```

How can I debug this?

**Update:**
I recently noticed this error being thrown when I run the plugin:

```
'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
```

Any help on how to debug this?

Comment: are you sure you're not confusing liburl2 with [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) ?

Comment: Yeah, I did a typo but corrected it later... urllib2 is not working for me... thanks for pointing that out though :p

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of Python installed? Check which one Vim uses by executing `:python import sys; print sys.version`.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this command works (without error):

```
:python import urllib2
```

Probably, the Python interpreter that your Vim is using is missing some libraries. Check your *import path* via

```
:python print sys.path
```

On my system, it prints this:

```
['D:\\must>not&exist', 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Program
Files\\Python\\2.7\\Lib', 'C:\\Program Files\\Python\\2.7\\DLLs',
'C:\\Program Files\\Python\\2.7\\Lib\\lib-tk', 'D:\\HOME\\vimfiles\\doc',
'c:\\Program Files\\vim\\vim73', 'C:\\Program Files\\Python\\2.7',
'C:\\Program Files\\Python\\2.7\\lib\\site-packages']
```

Comment: You have a problem here: vim has C code to filter out path `must>not&exist`, but this path is present in your output. You should report a bug if it is also present in most recent vim version.

Comment: thanks for sys.path suggestion. I checked that my sys.path does not contain python's lib, lib-tk and dll directories. Now, how do I correct this?